# Self join to get common students for a list of teachers

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, join

I am writing an back-end APIs in Node.js using Express.js.

In one of the APIs I need to return the list of students which are common to a given list of teachers.

For example, if

- Teacher1 teaches Tom, Jerry and Ed.
- Teacher2 teaches Ed, Eddy and Jerry.
- Teacher3 teaches Ed, Edd and Eddy.

The API takes in the input of list of teachers `[Teacher1, Teacher2, Teacher3]`. Then the output should be `[Ed]`, since its the only common student between the three teachers.

Here is the Register table which defines the association between the teachers and students.

```
id | teacher_email    | student_email       | valid |
41 | Tom@gmail.com    | May@gmail.com       |     1 |
42 | Tom@gmail.com    | jerry@gmail.com     |     1 |
43 | Tom@gmail.com    | Kestov@gmail.com    |     1 |
44 | Toni@gmail.com   | hdjh@kd.com         |     1 |
58 | larry@gmail.com  | jerry@gmail.com     |     1 |
59 | gerrad@gmail.com | jerry@gmail.com     |     1 |
60 | gerrad@gmail.com | Kestov@gmail.com    |     1 |
61 | gerrad@gmail.com | Katrin@gmail.com    |     1 |
62 | gerrad@gmail.com | Piniyara@gniail.com |     1 |
63 | gerrad@gmail.com | Ritz@gmail.com      |     1 |
64 | gerrad@gmail.com | Taz@gmail.com       |     1 |
65 | gerrad@gmail.com | Fensuk@gmail.com    |     1 |
66 | gerrad@gmail.com | Joe@gmail.com       |     1 |
67 | gerrad@gmail.com | Mustafa@gmail.com   |     1 |
69 | Tom@gmail.com    | Fensuk@gmail.com    |     1 |
70 | Tom@gmail.com    | Taz@gmail.com       |     1 |
```

I tried writing a self join query but its giving out all the students for all the teachers in the input. Here it is:

```
  const commonStudentsForTeachersQueryString = "SELECT a.student_email "+
  "FROM register a, register b "+
  "WHERE b.teacher_email=a.teacher_email "+
  "AND "+
  "a.teacher_email in (?) "+
  "AND "+
  "a.valid=? "+
  "GROUP BY a.student_email";
```

Although, alternatively option for getting all the students for each teacher in a loop and `Intersecting` them is there, but it's not optimal. I want to make use of one query only to get the common students for the list a teachers.

[Here](https://github.com/harshvardhan/nodejs_api) is the GitHub Repo for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked:

```
SELECT a.student_email FROM register a JOIN register b ON a.teacher_email = b.teacher_email WHERE a.teacher_email IN (?) And a.valid=1 GROUP BY a.student_email HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.teacher_email)=?
```

Former argument being the **email Ids of teachers** and its **size** as the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `having` for this purpose:

```
select r.student_email
from register r
where r.teacher_email in (?, ?, ?)
group by r.student_email
having count(distinct teacher_email) = 3;
```

The `count(distinct)` is because -- at least theoretically -- a student could have the same teacher for two different classes.

The `3` is the number of teachers that need to match.

EDIT:

Another method uses `intersect`:

```
select r.student_email
from registrations r
where r.teacher_email = ?
intersect
select r.student_email
from registrations r
where r.teacher_email = ?
intersect
select r.student_email
from registrations r
where r.teacher_email = ?;
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon, thanks. I tried this query, I am getting all the students which are not common. So precisely exact opposite of the desired result.

Comment: @HarshVardhan . . . You are misinterpreting the results.  There is no way this query can return students that are *not* common among the three.

Comment: I checked again..you can see the results here. https://imgur.com/a/OELoGXv

Comment: I tried the intersect query but I am getting an ER_PARSE_ERROR with it: http://collabedit.com/gagmm

Comment: Hey @Gordon, just came to know we can't use INTERSECT in MySQL.

Comment: @HarshVardhan . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle of some sort?

Comment: sure @Gordon, let me set it up and get back to you!

Comment: Here you go @Gordon: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6T2mHuzuhC9bDu6kafETyc/0